# Fetching most popular tweets for a particular country using iOS Twitter.framework

Tags: ios, twitter, ios8

I need to fetch most popular tweets for a particular country using Twitter.framework.

Couldn't find any documentation on this.

Has anyone worked on it?

Comment: Where have you looked?

Answer (score 0):

Source: 
https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/search/tweets

You are interested in parameters `q` and `result_type` which has "popular" tag.

Country
For country you need to do `GET geo/search` for country.
Source: https://dev.twitter.com/ads/campaigns/geo-casting

So make a request to `GET geo/search`
After that call `GET search` with parameter `q=place:{PLACE_ID}` 
Also set parameter `result_type: popular`